# how to show that $A_kB_k\to AB?$

Tags: normed-spaces

> Let in the space $M(n,\mathbb R)=$ set of all $n\times n$ real matrices endowned with $\| \cdot \|_2,~A_k\to A,~B_k\to B.$ Then how to show that $A_kB_k\to AB?$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the triangular inequality with

$$A_kB_k-AB=A_k(B_k-B)+(A_k-A)B$$

Answer (score 1):

The map $(A,B) \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})^{2} \, \longmapsto \, AB$ is continuous on $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})^{2}$ as it is bilinear on a finite dimensional space.